# Getting MySql command result in servlet java

Tags: java, jdbc

Basically I am trying to find how many people in mysql database are registered by a specific name using `SELECT` command with my java program. The command executes without any error but the result is something different than I have in my db.

Here is my java code I am using to get UIDs:

```
public void usernameAvail_fun(){
    String query = "SELECT UID FROM db.tb WHERE UFN=\"myuid\"";
    ResultSet ursa;
    try {
        ursa = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(ursa.toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and i happen to get the result as: `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@11719758`

Comment: Initialize ursa to null first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a java object so output is there. If you want to print uid use following statement -

```
while (ursa.next()){
    System.out.println(ursa.getString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `ursa` to `null` first.

adding a `PreparedStatement`

```
public void usernameAvail_fun(){
  String query = "SELECT UID FROM db.tb WHERE UFN=\"myuid\"";
   ResultSet ursa= null;
try {
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ursa= stmt.executeQuery();
  while(ursa.next()) //print
 {
   ursa.getString(1); //or ursa.getString("//your column name");
 }
} 


catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: i just did it, but no changes, the result is still the same